# How to use simple theme in struts2

Tags: struts2

I am new to the Stuts2 framework.  I am using multiple struts2 UI tags, but the labels are not  visible. The code is as follows:

```
<div>
    <s:textfield name="firstName" label="First Name"  theme="simple" />
    <s:textfield name="middleName" label="Middle Name" theme="simple"/>
    <s:textfield name="lastName" label="Last Name" theme="simple"/>
    <s:textfield name="empId" label="Employee Id" theme="simple"/>
</div>
```

I want these UI tags to be in a single row with their labels.

Answer (score 3):

Then remove `theme="simple"` ;

Simple Theme will NOT generate any additional HTML markup, allowing you to fully control the output;

XHTML Theme (that is the default) will instead decorate your tags with labels, tables etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Struts2 tags are themed using FreeMarker. You can either change from the simple theme to the default XHTML theme by specifying the following in your struts.properties:

```
# Standard UI theme
struts.ui.theme=xhtml
```

Or you can override the theme for just those tags by adding the theme attribute as follows:

```
<div>
    <s:textfield name="firstName" label="First Name"  theme="xhtml" />
    <s:textfield name="middleName" label="Middle Name" theme="xhtml"/>
    <s:textfield name="lastName" label="Last Name" theme="xhtml"/>
    <s:textfield name="empId" label="Employee Id" theme="xhtml"/>
</div>
```

Here's some [additional information about themes](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/struts-2-themes.html).